# SEDE quick-view of CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes table does not match query result

Tags: support, data-explorer

- #5 quick-view is about super-user, but query is about SSCCE
- #6 quick-view is about career / office politics, but query is about minimal understanding
- #7 quick-view is about what tech to learn next, but query is about on-topic specific programming [...]
- #10 quick-view is about MCVE, but query is about minimal understanding
- #11 quick-view is about off-site resource recommendation, but query is about typo/cannot-reproduce
- #12 quick view is about legal advice, but query is about MCVE
- #13 quick-view is about MCVE, but query is about MRE
- #14 quick-view is about MRE, but query is about off-site resource recommendation
- #15 quick-view is about MRE/MCVE, but query is about off-site resource recommendation

Am I just crazy and looking at two completely unrelated tables? I copy-and-pasted the table name to query. What's with the differences?

```sql
SELECT R.Id, R.InputTitle, R.MarkdownPublicGuidance
FROM CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes R
```

Comment: "super-user" is probably *[superuser](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superuser#Noun)*, not the Stack Exchange site [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour). [SSCCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) = short self-contained correct example. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) = minimal, complete and verifiable example. MRE = minimal, reproducible example (AKA REPREX).

Comment: Related: *[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677)*